# Host Binding rearranges applied classes

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular2-hostbinding

I am using `@HostBinding('class')` to inject classes into the host element. The classes to be injected are generated based on user-supplied parameters. The problem I ran into and I could not find anyone else experiencing is that the classes are applied in an order different from the way I expected them.

For example, having a component defined below:

```js
import {Component, HostBinding, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[icon]',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `
})
export class SuiIconComponent {
  @Input() iconType = '';

  @HostBinding('class')
  get classes(): string {
    return [this.iconType, 'icon'].join((' '));
  }
}
```

When I apply the component like shown below:

```html
<div icon iconType="car"></div>
```

And inspect, I see `<div class="icon car"></div>` instead of the appropriately formatted `<div class="car icon"></div>`.
I have tried reversing the array before joining but that did not help either.
Is there any way I get the classes to get rendered in the proper order?

Edit: I realized the classes are being rearranged in alphabetic order.

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: I am do not have control over the CSS lib and for the styling to get applied appropriately, the order has to be maintained

Comment: Can you share the css style that `icon car` renders something different than `car icon`? I haven't seen an example where order of css classes on the same element matter

Comment: This deals with the semantic ui styles some of which e.g `action left` instead of `left action` would simply not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why angular changes the order, but you can solve your problem with little bit of change in your template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'icon',
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="iconType + ' icon'">
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class SuiIconComponent {
  @Input() iconType = '';
}
```

and use it as follows

```
<icon iconType="car">
   Some content here
</icon>
```

Comment: I do not want to create a component as such, I want my component to modify what the user has and give them the leeway to make further changes as they see fit instead of giving them a backed component

Comment: You already created a component and used it as directive. In my case, you would use it as element and nothing would change